# How to reduce multiple if conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having multiple conditions in if as bellow

```
if((readCookie("endData") != "" && 
  readCookie("lastRowArray") != "" && 
  readCookie("histClickedImgId") != "" && 
  readCookie("histClickedPage") != "" && 
  readCookie("remove_count") != "" && 
  readCookie("histBack") != "") && 
  (readCookie("endData") && 
  readCookie("lastRowArray") && 
  readCookie("histClickedImgId") && 
  readCookie("histClickedPage") && 
  readCookie("remove_count") && 
  readCookie("histBack") )){ 
    cdtChecked = true;  
}
```

Is there any way to reduce the code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is needing a codereview. belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: well you **must** check those conditions..

Comment: _"Is there any way to reduce the code."_ - Well there are two sets of redundant parentheses that you could remove. Is there some reason why the first six conditions check for a non empty string but the last six conditions just test for any truthy value?

Comment: @Mr_Green you must check but there must be an easier and more elegant way, don't you think so ?

Comment: @lukas.pukenis yeah.. chop those conditions in variables, I suppose..

Comment: use a function f() and check these conditions in it. Check if f() returns true in the 'if' statement.

Comment: @Mr_Green, watch my answer

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Your answer could still be improved. `['endData', ...].every(function (item) { return readCookie(item) });` THere's no need to check for `''` since it's falsey and the native [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function allows to check all conditions.

Comment: @plalx no doubt about that. But if op can't figure out himself how to reduce this code I doubt he knows how to use higher order functions

Comment: @plalx `every` is not available on IE8 which might be an issue.

Comment: @millimoose That's really not a concern, you should use es5-shim.

Comment: @plalx this is a question not about shims or browser compatibility. Please do not discuss now about underscore or lodash. There are other questions suitable for these advices.

Comment: @lukas.pukenis Listing all the caveats of a proposed solution is appropriate for any question. plalx' suggestion does have the caveat that without including ES5-shim it's incompatible with a large amount of browsers, pointing out a fix is on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can write a new function like this:

```
function allCookiesSet() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var arg = arguments[i];     
    if (!readCookie(arg)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT:**
To remove confusion, there's no need to check if cookie is set and/or if it's empty.. Empty strings evalute to **false** in javascript.

```
if (allCookiesSet(cookies) ) { ... }
```

Comment: But the OP's code isn't doing the same `!= ""` test on every line. I really don't know what the goal is, but first the six cookies are tested for inequality with an empty string, and then the same six cookies are tested for any truthy value.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have updated my code according to your insights

Comment: Isn't the method `allCookiesSet` is enough? I am just asking.. because `!''` _is equal to_ `true`.

Comment: @Mr_Green yes, you're right :)